# locking database table while deleting records - understanding "Read Committed" transaction isolation in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, transactions, lua

I have a web app that will provide a feature to delete a widget that belong to a user. 
The logic I have right now to do the delete looks like this:

```
local delete_widget = function(widgetid, user)
   local retval = ""      

         sql = "DELETE FROM widgets Where widgetid="..widgetid
         cur, err = assert(con:execute(sql))
         if not err then
               sql = "SELECT * FROM widgets where widgetid = ".. widgetid
               listofwidgets = executesqlandreturntable(sql)
               if #listofwidgets == 0 then
                    retval = "Deleted widget"
               else
                    retval = "Unable to delete widget"
               end
         else
               retval = "unable to delete widget"
         end 
   return retval
end
```

What I'm wondering is if i should change this to be a transaction.  Right now, if the deletion attempt fails for whatever reason, I'm not doing anything. 
I just do a select to see if it still exists and if it does, i throw an error.

I'm wondering if I should do the full begin transaction/commit / rollback so that if the select statement finds that the widget still exists, it will rollback the delete sql statement.

But I have the following questions:

1. How do I use pgadmin3 to check what the current value is for my transaction isolation level?
2. If I leave it as the default - which according to what I've read is "read committed" - that will lock the widgets table while I'm finished both the delete and the select commands, correct?  This would mean that no one else can select from the widgets table until this transaction is complete, right?  That doesn't sound like a good thing, given I will have hundreds of users.

Any comments / suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it LuaSQL? Can you provide/read the documentation? What is `executesqlandreturntable`?

Comment: hjpotter92, i am using luasql...but  think the settings in postgresql are more relevant since luasql is just the driver for postgresql.  I guess I'm looking better understand the principles behind "read committed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't know.
2. Modern databases allow you to acquire locks on row levels, without necessarily locking entire tables, which is highly inneficient. So in this instance, only row level locks will be acquired until transaction is complete. That means that other users will be able to select from the table, but only rows that are not locked by your transaction.

I don't know why you issue another select after you delete the row. The delete should be either successful or the query would return an error (due to lock time out, for example). There's no need to check again.

So in this instance starting a transaction is not necessary, as DELETE acquires write lock on that row implicitly. Unless autocommit is turned off, then you'd have to commit anyway.